# Kendo Treeview checkChildren property not to uncheck Parent when child unchecked

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

We are using kendo treeview to display hierarchial datasource.

One of our requirement is to check/uncheck all children checkboxes when a parent is checked/unchecked, so we used checkChildren property to achieve this.

But the issue is when we uncheck a child, the parent should not get unchecked, even if we have one child inside the parent.

Can you please provide jquery code snippet to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is less complicated to write your own check children function. Just use this function in `check` event:

```
function onCheck(e) {
    var chbx = $(e.node).find('.k-checkbox input').filter(":first");
    var state = chbx.is(':checked');
    $(e.node).find(".k-group input").prop('checked', state);

    //check the dataSource elements
    $(e.node).find(".k-group li.k-item").each(function(i,v){
        e.sender.dataSource.getByUid($(v).attr('data-uid')).checked = state;
    });
}
```

Also, here is the snippet you want: http://dojo.telerik.com/AFOqA

Comment: in my case I had to replace `'.k-checkbox input'` with `'input[type=checkbox]'`